# Adding Foreign key but getting constraint violation error

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I have four tables:

```
1)Country:Two columns
  a) country_id
  b) country_name

2)State: Three columns
  a) state_id
  b) state_name
  c) country_id(foreign key)

 3)City: Three Columns
   a) city_id
   b) city_name
   c) state_id(foreign key)

 4) Doctor: 20 Columns
   a) doc_id (primary key)
   b) doc_name
   c) email,gender age and so on
```

I have populated these tables with dara.

I am adding three new columns: country_id, state_id and city_id in doctor table as a foreign key.

When I insert the country_id, state_id and city_id as a foreign key in that table I got this error

```
1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`medical_network`.`#sql-4174_45`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-4174_45_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `country` (`country_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

I know this is a basic error, but can't find the mistake.

Doctor Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `doctor` (
 `doc_id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `doc_fname` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `doc_lname` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `doc_province` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `doc_city` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `doc_gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `doc_fathername` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `doc_age` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `doc_cnic` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
 `doc_medclgname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `doc_specilization` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `doc_phoneno` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `doc_officeno` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `doc_email` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `doc_gradyear` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `doc_licenseno` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `doc_hosp` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `doc_pass` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
 `doc_address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `doc_country` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `doc_img` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `totime` time NOT NULL,
 `fromtime` time NOT NULL,
 `todate` date NOT NULL,
 `fromdate` date NOT NULL,
 `country_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`doc_id`),
 KEY `country_id` (`country_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin
```

Country Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `country` (
 `country_id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `country_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`country_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=252 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

State Table Query:

```
CREATE TABLE `state` (
 `state_id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `state_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `country_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`state_id`),
 KEY `country_id` (`country_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `state_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `country` (`country_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

City Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `city` (
 `city_id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `city_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `state_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`city_id`),
 KEY `state_id` (`state_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `city_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`state_id`) REFERENCES `state` (`state_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Show the structure of `Doctor`.

Comment: Post create table statements of all those parent and child tables involved.

Comment: Your `create` statements are pretty fine. Problem can be with existing data that do not match with relation. Please check if any mismatched data is present in the *child* tables

Comment: The doctor id is present as a foreign key in two more tables but i don't think by adding a column will affect on that child tables.

Comment: Check if all country_id's that are present in the doctor tables relate to an existing ID in the country table before adding the FK

Comment: @DarkBee  When i make a relation of country_id in doctor table to country_id of country table then I get the error specified before

Comment: Yes, because there is a country_id in the doctor table which is not matching a valid ID forced by the FK

Comment: @DarkBee I am relating with the valid country_id but giving me the same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. First Add All the columns you want to make foreign keys in the Table.
2. Add some relevant data into it.
3. Now Alter the table and make those new added column a foreign key.

   ie
   ALTER TABLE TblName
   AD FOREIGN KEY (P_Id)
   REFERENCES ParentTable(P_Id)

Answer (score 1):

#### In English:

You have some doctors who are in unknown countries.

#### In DB-speak:

One or more rows of `doctor` have a value for `country_id` that in not found in the `country_id` column of `country`.

Check that the values of `country_id` for new doctor rows exist in the country table.

To find them if doctor rows already exist:

```
select d.*
from doctor d
left join country c on c.country_id = doctor.country_id
where c.country_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the column country_id int(20) NULL in 'doctor' table